# How do I use a function in String.replace() in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using the function "linkify" to add a HTML link tag to a message, and it works.
I'm now trying to shorten long URL, I've made a function for that.

How can I pass this function to the "replace" method?

```
 shortenURL(source: string, maxSize: number) {
    return source.length <= maxSize ? source : source.toString().substr(maxSize - 3) + "...";
  }

  linkify(inputText) {
    var replacedText, replacePattern1;

    //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
    replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
    replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(replacedText);
  }
```

[TypesScript Playground with minimal code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbADvAdgUzQF2gbwChpoIALeAJ2ywFUAlAGQAoJ4BXC4DALhOwoCWaAOYAaaIjAAPAMoCAXj2ho2iAEYYKASnxFi0Chmwc0JdpwwA6EFmHZS0ADwBeCdLmLoAfjMcu0XlY-K2x4GX4hYSYtSwg2NQh%20JklZBQxoAFpoAGYdAGpoACJLEsKAbj0AXwI9ECEAawEAMwBPJiFkNmwAFQwpXECIkR1CfWgANzAKAwxkcC4AE17%208UM5sC4ABTBsago0AEYKvWIAelP6BhhEqexI6AB3AXtoUl3kbnPxN%20xkCE-TuJKNAmr8AScZustjs9odoK5TkwADpqJg-P5eAA%20oOQWm4SNOBIA2hkAIIZABaAAYMgBOPIAMgAAgBiAkAUi8zgAfgB9TEAQm4oksZQAugAqEnk6l0xmsjk8-lirSnYQCRAVMZreYYJZ9XCuDpdZbYSw6jYYJgW6G7TSHcQAckcYFehiazkKABIDoVoNgpsIjJ7eWpwGh6oUAHw%20xynMBRx1aY7aowmSG6-X9LXQarVAiTabAXgIFDoLCG5QYB5wJCoTA4CrAdCJaAcEDworo-7nG7AerwcaaJogeAPSzNxCnACObAwiQELdOADZsgB2ZdrgAcy%20Xp3IDwyC3gGQEGTYEAwGTAGSabDQwDu6FPaAyiUEIgyNqvQgy2BayDzsAgjINg5QEM2aCsDY1jwFEwDWA0zRtO2WjJjU5zQJBrZ1BGnYIbhjStBUmHYbghHIdwdCzLq0yuIRlhqEICxMMA6GkS2uCGHEICVhRrRMKhZRAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrote this method, and it's doing what I want. I'm using the "function" of replace. I don't know if I'm using it right, but I have difficulties to find documentation and examples about it.

```
class Component {
  linkify(inputText : string, maxSize: number) {
    var replacedText, replacePattern;

    replacePattern = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;

    replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern, function(a, b, c, d, e){
        let ret = "";
        let displayedURL = a.length <= maxSize ? a : a.toString().substr(0, maxSize- 3) + "...";
        ret += "<a href=\"" + a + "\" target =\"_blank\">" + displayedURL + "</a>";
        return ret;
  });
    
    return replacedText;
  }
}
```

[Playground implementation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbADvAdgUzQF2gbwChpoQBLNAa1IDMBPACnOQFdsAVDAD1wC5oJsAJ3IBzADTREYTgGVSALwx80zRACMMggJT4ixaADcwg6IIzJwwDABMO3CWYtgrABTDZsmtAG4Ce4o6WGG4eXtAAvNAA9PQAOmr0ABYeyBAA-AA%201NjIWjyxUQUA2gC0AIIlAFoADCUAnADUAGQAAgDEBQCkaeEAfgD6GQCEPGIAdN4AugBUpRU19c3tXX2Dk1pRIqSIvv6m5kG2XLiRTKx22GOBzhj0167unoJoEtTMaMDYpOj0YBJqEmAEmsEgwWkI%20khJAwuDMJ2gACIEb4ofoQDDoNZSBAnLQbABVABKABkItAwGN0WgRNhEtAADyRKSyBQYaBpcnQPgU7DwGRCUT0LRjCDMNQCQT0aoSZlyRQlaAAZh0DURY3VyL2kLh0AakQR9LA0ESZmo4ViSN1nNVCIt0GwxhEGPNCP6anAlAtAD4EVasTjwHjrETSTb6VEwD6Uaj9thmM9Y9GAL5aaPEPZw%20NofZOKxHbjJghJvxGEzAPgIFDoLDwzAAdzgSFQmBwvmA6AE0HjIDJCIAsrRoABHZgYATfbNkSjQbHGlIQHhRKICZwUeAGTTUEDwOtjduIKIjsdfDtRABsioA7GfLwAOM9nqKJHclazwEqkErMCAYEpgEpvB8J5oB%20IESqIJT3L%205AlNgtDIGOwDCMglyau2aAQPA6KUvAIj0MAlLkFQdD0N2EiKgATFoqZAA)